# Bootstrap 2.3.2 responsive design too slow in IE8

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

### **Background**

I've built a responsive website template. I've chosen to use **Bootstrap 2.3.2** because it needs to work in IE7+ and be suitable for mobile devices. I've used respond.js and html5shiv.js so that it will work in IE.

### **Problem**

The site works beautifully in Chrome and Firefox. And it displays well in IE8. However **in IE8 it's incredibly slow**. Even after the page has finished loading the browser freezes up if I try to scroll down or click on something. It looks great but the slow response time makes it virtually unusable.

### **Cause of problem**

I've identified that **Bootstrap.min.css** is the cause. When I remove bootstrap.min.css from the page and leave everything else the same, the styles don't work but the page loads quickly and it's very quick to scroll up and down and click on buttons.

I think (or rather I hope!) that the cause is not Bootstrap but rather because I'm using the **responsive** elements of Bootstrap (e.g. row-fluid). I'd like to keep the site responsive for all non-IE users, but I'd like to try making all widths fixed for IE8 users and below.

### **Attempts to fix**

I've tried overriding the percentage widths in IE by creating a conditional IE stylesheet. However it doesn't appear to be possible to override the media queries, even using !important (example below).

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid"> 
       <div class="span10 width7">

       </div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap**

This is an example of what I've been trying to override.

```
 @media (min-width: 1200px)
      .row-fluid .span10 {
      width: 40.92827004219409%;
      }
```

**CSS to override Bootstrap**

The code below is not able to override the bootstrap css above.

```
.row-fluid .span10.width7{  
      width:  485px !important; 
 }
```

### **Question**

Has anyone got any suggestions about how I might adapt my template so that it continues to be responsive for non-IE users but has fixed widths for IE8 and below?

Many thanks,

Katie

Comment: IE8 doesn't support media queries, so if you've got IE8 using them, then I guess you're including a polyfill library like respond.js that adds support for them to IE8. If you are using this, then that is likely to be the cause of your performance issues. But also, it makes it easy to resolve the issue, simply by removing the polyfill (especially since you've stated that you're okay with IE8 not being responsive).

Comment: Aside from what @Spudley said I've had some bad experience with MS specific CSS such as the `filter:` property with imageTransform filters for gradients or shadows. They blocked IE8 in an unresponsive state until the filters were fully applied.

Comment: I didn't have my problems with bootstrap but with a little JQuery lightbox plugin such as FancyBox or jQuery.LightBox but I just checked the bootstrap.css and apparently it contains MS specific CSS including `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(...);`

Comment: Thanks both for your constructive comments. I'll certainly try removing the polyfill - it will be great if it's as easy to resolve as that! I wouldn't have suspected the gradients were to blame! I think I've overridden most of them because I don't want them anyway, but it'll certainly be worth me checking that carefully. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Hi @MihaiStancu - I've tried removing my js polyfillers and the page still runs slowly, so now I'm going to try dealing with your filter suggestion. This seems like a likely culprit! How would you recommend I deal with the issue? Did you delete the filter from your original code? Or would it work to simply override it in a separate stylesheet like this:

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);`

Many thanks!

Comment: Since the CSS is usually in the `<head>` and images are brought into the mix via HTML `<img>` or via CSS `url()` the `filter` things need to wait until all images are loaded before applying their stuff. For me, at that time, it was enough to move the entire `lightbox.css` at the end of the HTML document (before `</body>`).

Comment: For me that was fine because the lightbox CSS was used only after clicking an image. But obviously for you the CSS styles the entire page and that can mean your page will experience a longer duration of [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). So moving the entire bootstrap.css (and all subsequent css) to the end of the `<body>` might be acceptable or you might need to keep it at the top and only move the `filter:` properties to the bottom.